# How can I get the current user groups in my aspx page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, groups, membership

I am trying to filter some webparts based on user's group in my SharePoint Default.aspx page. To do this, I want to define if a user is member of a group first and then use a conditional statement to show the webpart or hide it.

```
<% condition = CheckCurrentUserMembership("Group Name"); 
if(condition) { %>

<div>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="my_requests_View" Title="loc:full">

    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>

<% } %>
```

I wanted to know what is the code that can work like **CheckCurrentUserMembership** function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST api for this:

```
function getData(siteurl) {
var endpoint = siteurl+"/_api/web/currentuser/groups";
$.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var data= data.d.results;
        var len = data.length;        
        for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
             console.log(data[i].Title); //outputs group title
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

This will give you the title of all groups of the current user. You can modify that with what you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Target Audience** property of webpart. This is out of box and available in webpart properties in "Advance".

[image]

In Target Audience, you can add a SharePoint group and webpart will be visible for that group only.

For reference:[Target content to specific audience](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-files-links-and-web-parts-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Still if you want know whether user belongs to specific group. You can use below code:

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroup managerGroup = site.Groups["Your_Group_Name"];

bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup.ID);
```

[Reference](https://pawansatope.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-find-out-spuser-belongs-to.html)

Comment: I am writing an application and I want to avoid any after development configuration. Is there any way that I can make this configuration inside my .aspx file where I put my WebParts codes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the current user logged in is a member of some group, you can use the code below:

```
    public static bool CheckAdminUser()
    {
        var isMember = false;
        try
        {
            using (var oSite = new SPSite(PortalUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    var spGroup = oWeb.Groups["AdminGroup"];
                    if (spGroup != null)
                    {
                        isMember = oWeb.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(spGroup.ID);
                    }
                }
            }
            return isMember;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return isMember;
        }
    }
```